# Updating Google Doc script to Google Drive (Archive emails with tags to drive)

Tags: google-apps-script

My script saves pdf versions of emails with a specific label to Google drive.  I have three nearly identical versions of the script for three different labels and I run them periodically.

Recently they stopped working because of depreciation of DocsList.  I changed all the instances of DocsList to DriveApp, but now am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot find function createFolder in object FolderIterator."

The issue is in the last few lines, where the script should be creating a folder in which to save the pdf of the emails.

Could someone help me fix the createFolder function and get the script back up and running?

```js
/**
 * Main function run at spreadsheet opening
 */
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ 
    {name: "Initialize", functionName: "init"},
    {name: "Archive Gmail Messages", functionName: "ScanGmail"}
  ];
  ss.addMenu("Gmail Archiver", menuEntries);
}
    
/**
 * Initialize the system
 */
function init() {
    // Create the needed Gmail label
    GmailApp.createLabel("Archive to Drive");
    
    // Create Google Drive folder if doesn't exists
    try {
       var folder = DriveApp.getFolder("Email Archive");
    } catch(e) {
       // Folder doesn't exists
       DriveApp.createFolder("Email Archive");
    }
    
    Browser.msgBox("Created Gmail label: Archive to Drive and Google Drive folder: Email Archive");
}

/**
 * Scan Gmail account for message archive requests
 */
function ScanGmail() {
  // Default Drive folder where to archive messages
  var baseFolder = "Sparkfly Receipts 2015";
  
  // Get the label
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Sparkfly receipt");
    var threadsArr = getThreadsForLabel(label);
    for(var j=0; j<threadsArr.length; j++) {
      var messagesArr = getMessagesforThread(threadsArr[j]);
      for(var k=0; k<messagesArr.length; k++) {
        var messageId = messagesArr[k].getId();
        var messageDate = Utilities.formatDate(messagesArr[k].getDate(), Session.getTimeZone(), "MM.dd.yyyy");
        var messageFrom = messagesArr[k].getFrom();
        var messageSubject = messagesArr[k].getSubject();
        var messageBody = messagesArr[k].getBody();
        var messageAttachments = messagesArr[k].getAttachments();
        
        // Create the new folder to contain the message
        var newFolderName = messageDate + " - " + messageSubject;
        var newFolder = createDriveFolder(baseFolder, newFolderName);
        
        // Create the message PDF inside the new folder
        var htmlBodyFile = newFolder.createFile('body.html', messageBody, "text/html");
        var pdfBlob = htmlBodyFile.getAs('application/pdf');
        pdfBlob.setName(newFolderName + ".pdf");
        newFolder.createFile(pdfBlob);
        htmlBodyFile.setTrashed(true);
        

        // Save attachments
        for(var i = 0; i < messageAttachments.length; i++) {
            var attachmentName = messageAttachments[i].getName();
            var attachmentContentType = messageAttachments[i].getContentType();
            var attachmentBlob = messageAttachments[i].copyBlob();
            newFolder.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        }

      }
      // Remove Gmail label from archived thread
      label.removeFromThread(threadsArr[j]);
    }
    Browser.msgBox("Gmail messages successfully archived to Google Drive");
}


/**
 * Find all user's Gmail labels that represent mail message
 * movement requests es: moveto->xx@yyyy.com
 *
 * @return {GmailLabel[]} Array of GmailLabel objects
 */
function scanLabels() {
  // logs all of the names of your labels
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  var results = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if(labels[i].getName() == "Sparkfly receipt") {
      results.push(labels[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

/**
 * Get all Gmail threads for the specified label
 *
 * @param {GmailLabel} label GmailLabel object to get threads for
 * @return {GmailThread[]} an array of threads marked with this label
 */
function getThreadsForLabel(label) {
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  return threads;
}

/**
 * Get all Gmail messages for the specified Gmail thread
 *
 * @param {GmailThread} thread object to get messages for
 * @return {GmailMessage[]} an array of messages contained in the specified thread
 */
function getMessagesforThread(thread) {
  var messages = thread.getMessages();
  return messages;
}


/**
 * Get methods of an object
 * @param {Object} object to scan
 * @return {Array} object's methods
 */
function getMethods(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var id in obj) {
    try {
      if (typeof(obj[id]) == "function") {
        result.push(id + ": " + obj[id].toString());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      result.push(id + ": inaccessible");
    }
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Create a Google Drive Folder
 *
 * @param {String} baseFolder name of the base folder
 * @param {String} folderName name of the folder
 * @return {Folder} the folder object created representing the new folder 
 */
function createDriveFolder(baseFolder, folderName) {
  var baseFolderObject = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(baseFolder);
  return baseFolderObject.createFolder(folderName);
}
```

Comment: DocsList is deprecated, you need to do more than just rename instances to DriveApp. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29973748/1677912) for a similar question shows the use of iterators in the new DriveApp.

Comment: Yes.  I was hoping for some help in what more I need to do.  But I've since found it. 

I just needed to add .next() to the end of the line that calls getFoldersByName.

Comment: @Dan If you have more than one folder with the same name (in more than one location or even in the same location, .next() gives you one of them, but not necessarily the right one at the right time. You might want to use the whole path to identify which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method getFoldersByName() returns a [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator) (collection of folder objects), and that collections does not contain a "createFolder" method.

So if the collection has at least one Folder object you should take that object out of the collection and then call "createFolder".

Here you can find the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFoldersByName(String)

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know enough to understand all of this, but a friend helped me find that I just need to add .next() to the end of the line that calls getFoldersByName.