# Show Files In Folder not Working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have received the error '"DocsList" is not defined.' to my script which was working fine untill the 'DocsList' was disabled. I surched online to a possible solution to this matter and found that I must change the 'DocsList' to 'DriveApp' in order for my script to work. However, no information is being poplated. I do not know what is wrong. Any help please?

Original version:

```
function ShowFilesInFolder() {
var files = DocsList.getFolderById(id).getFolders();

// Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

// Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
var headers = [["Folder Name", "Owner", "URL"]];
sheet.clear();
sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);


// Loop through the results and display the file name, file type, and URL
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).setValue(files[i].getName());
sheet.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 1).setValue(files[i].getOwner());

sheet.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1).setValue('https://drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#folders/' + files[i].getId());
  }
}
```

Amended Version:

```
   function ShowFilesInFolder() {
   var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
   var files = DriveApp.getFolders();

// Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

// Set up the spreadsheet to display the results
   var headers = [["Folder Name", "Owner", "URL"]];
   sheet.clear();
   sheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(headers);


// Loop through the results and display the file name, file type, and URL
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).setValue(files[i].getName());
   sheet.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 1).setValue(files[i].getOwner());

   sheet.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1).setValue('https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive' + files[i].getId());
  }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Google Doc script to Google Drive (Archive emails with tags to drive)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990522/updating-google-doc-script-to-google-drive-archive-emails-with-tags-to-drive)

Answer (score 0):

`DriveApp.getFolders();` doesn't return an Array, but a GAS class called [Folder Iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator), the documentation is short but all you need.

BTW, why is a variables that will contain folders called files?

And your code is really inefficient, please take a moment to read [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) on how to make a single call to write all your values.

Answer (score 0):

DocsList has been deprecated, you should replace it with something like:

```
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName([FILENAME]);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var data = files.next().getBlob().getDataAsString()
 }
```

or

```
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFolders();
  while (folder.hasNext()) {
    var x = folder.next()....
  }
```

... you've got the picture,  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You don't get an array from DriveApp .getFolders() but an iterator. It is possible to quickly map this over to an array or an object inside a `while` loop to completes as long as there is content still to process.

```
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
  // do stuff with folder
}
```

putting this together with processing the folders list into an two-dimensional array for more efficient SpreadsheetApp usage might lead to the below revision to your code.

```
function ShowSubfolders(name) {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name),
      folders = DriveApp.getFolders(),
      foldersArray = [],
      folder,
      ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      headers = [["Folder Name", "Owner", "URL"]],
      values = [];

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    foldersArray.push({name: folder.getName(), owner: folder.getOwner(), id: folder.getId(), url: folder.getUrl()});
  }

  // map folderArray to sheet format 
  values = headers.concat(folderArray.map(function(f) { return [f.name, f.owner, f.id, f.url]; }));

  sheet.clear();  
  sheet.getRange(1,1,folderValues.length + 1, 4).setValues(values);
}
```

Be aware that folders in Google Drive are not necessarily behaving as you are used to, in that everything is a reference/alias and the same folder can effectively be in multiple places at once, even though the other data you are looking for remains constant.